# Communicate node-exporter targets with SSL

Tags: docker, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm setting up a monitoring system with prometheus and node-exporter in Docker. I want to communicate node exporter targets over SSL.
Node-exporter working on port 9100. So I want to communicate with all targets using SSL on port 9100.
Illustration with diagram:

[image]

I'm using this repository: https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

There is an official [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/tls-encryption/) on how to set up a reverse proxy for this Case.

There are also Sandboxes/Examples with Docker in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/prometheus-community/prometheus-playground/tree/master/nginx).

Prometheus supports scraping targets via tls, so you just need to set up Nginx on the node exporter side but keep in mind that prometheus is unsecured by default, so you probably want to use a reverse proxy for prometheus as well and use Basic Auth.